# Why am I getting an error in my do/while loop with my object reference?

Tags: java

```
public boolean ChecktheNum()
{
    if (number == (int)number && number <= max && number >= 1)
    {
       return true;
    }

    return false;
}

do
{
    String num2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Guess a integer between 1 and "+max);
    int max2 = Integer.parseInt(num2);
    GuesstheNum game= new GuesstheNum(max2);
    game.ChecktheNum();
} while (game.ChecktheNum == false)
```

I'm having problems with my tester file, and the do while loop.
The error is coming up that `.game` is a symbol that cannot be found
Why is this?
The error keeps coming up even if I try a break method
Also I need to test whether the number inputted is an integer, this function is also not working as it is not asking for another input

Comment: Please make sure to tag your language. Is this [tag:java]?

Comment: I assume this is Java, if not, retag the question appropriately. You should also format/ident your code so that it is readable.

Comment: yes sorry this is java

Comment: Don't put "Java" in the title. That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do{ 
    ...
    GuesstheNum game= new GuesstheNum(max2);
    game.ChecktheNum();
}while(game.ChecktheNum == false)
```

`game` is not in the scope of the `while`. You can do this

```
GuesstheNum game;

do{ 
    ...
    game= new GuesstheNum(max2);
    game.ChecktheNum();
}while(game.ChecktheNum == false)
```

**Edit: try something like this**

```
    GuesstheNum game;
    boolean guess;
    do {
        String num2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Guess a integer between 1 and " + max);
        int max2 = Integer.parseInt(num2);
        game = new GuesstheNum(max2);
        guess = game.ChecktheNum();
    } while (guess);
```

More simply put

```
GuesstheNum game;

    do {
        String num2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Guess a integer between 1 and " + max);
        int max2 = Integer.parseInt(num2);
        game = new GuesstheNum(max2);
    } while (game.ChecktheNum());
```

**Edit: with integer check**

```
GuesstheNum game;
do {
    String num2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Guess a integer between 1 and " + max);
    int max2;
    try{
        int max2 = Integer.parseInt(num2);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        continue;
    }
    game = new GuesstheNum(max2);
} while (!game.ChecktheNum());
```

Comment: That worked!! i see my mistake in setting up the variables before the loop, but the second problem is if the user inputs a decimal number between 1 and the max, the loop should continue to ask for a number. But it is giving me a "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12.5"" how do i fix that? does there need to be a change in the method body?

Comment: I have edited another simpler version that works. Please don't for get to accept answer.

Comment: You need to `Double.parseDouble()` if you're getting an input that is not an integer. but then the arg to the GuesstheNum may not work. I'm assuming it takes an int in the constructor

Comment: yes of course, that will be definitely done,  but i also need help or the second part of my question

Comment: If you're asking the user to enter an integer, then why would you enter a double. You could catch the exception.

Comment: Where is `number` and `max` coming from? And what are they're values?

Comment: the number is coming from a user input and the max is coming from which game (1-10 or 1-100) they would like to play, so they will be able to choose between the two and the max will be set as either 10 or 100

Comment: Try changing the while to `while(!guess);` or `while(!game.ChecktheNum());`, depending on which version you chose.

Comment: I added a try/catch block to check to make sure number is an integer, if not, the message will pop up again.